# How do I calculate the HP of a level 20 Barbarian NPC with the Tough feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, npc, barbarian, hit-points

I'm a first time DM and I'm struggling with sorting out HP for a half orc NPC.

I rolled his HP and he has the tough feat that I gave him at level 4, so I know, at max, he gets 40 to his HP, but I'm unsure of how to actually calculate the total.

His CON is 22 and I rolled a total of 139 with the hit die + (12 hp + 4) for the first level.

What is the character's total HP?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you didn't just use the average roll of 6.5, or the rules' suggestion of 7hp per level? (it would have cut down on your trouble)

Comment: If you rolled his hitdie 19 times and added his Con + the Tough feat benefit, what is the problem with just adding up those rolls?

Comment: Related: [How do you determine hit points in 5e for custom monsters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84087), [Is Con modifier × level added to HP every level-up?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48156)

Comment: Your change from 139 to 155 is confusing because you seem to add in the 6 con from level one, which makes me wonder what else you added in.

Comment: okay so i'm a complete idiot, firstly thank you for your help. secondly the reason it went up was because i forgot to add the base level hp which was 12 + 4 which was 155. i forgot to mention i am super super bad at maths.

Answer (score 8):

Normally, Monsters and NPCs use a different system for Hit Points, however Hit Points from class levels are a combination of class hit-die rolls/averages, constitution modifiers, and (if applicable), any feats or extra abilities (such as hill dwarves or draconic sorcerers).

Constitution modifiers apply to every level, not just the levels after the modifiers were gained/increased.

So, at level 20, with a 22 Constitution, and the tough feat, we have:

- 12 from first level
- The 139 HP you rolled
- 120 HP from Constitution (modifier of 6 * 20 levels)
- 40 from the tough feat (2 per level, 20 levels)

### 311 HP

As a note, if you had taken the "recommended" hp of 7 per level and 12 at first level, you would have gotten 305HP, instead.